# Google Drive API ignores folder name

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a folder in Google Drive using its API and CURL, but it ignores the name I'm setting. My request:

```
curl -i \
  -H "X-Upload-Content-Type: application/vnd.google-apps.folder" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
  -d '{"name": "test"}' \
  https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files
```

`

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl -X POST -v \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
  -F "metadata={name: 'test', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'};type=application/json" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files"
```

You can also use the following command.

```
curl -X POST -v \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "{name: 'test', mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files"
```

#### Note:

- At this curl command, it supposes the following points.

  - Drive API is enabled.
  - Scopes which can create a folder are included for the access token.

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: First one did work for me. And the second one not. This is quite confusing, though, 'cause I do not see where Google documentation says I should use not just body, but form submission.

Comment: @Ngoral Thank you for replying. I could confirmed that in my environment, both patterns work fine. If you saw the error message when the 2nd one was run, can I ask you about it? I would like to study by knowing such information.

Comment: Just wait a minute... I am definitely sure the second one didn't work for me, and now it works. (There were no errors, just the name of the folder were not set after performing such a request). I'll investigate this some hours later and send some updates here.

Comment: @Ngoral Thank you for replying. I think that your information is useful for me and other users.

Comment: So, the problem was I didn't notice second request url does not have `upload` in it and it's a different url =)

Comment: @Ngoral Thank you for the information. I apologize that I forgot to clearly show that the endpoint was different.